# SASS generating URLs for multiple static

Tags: php, sass, compass-sass

The idea is that I use some mixin to generate domain for the images. Assuming I have 2 domains which have the same images I want to be able to load half the images from one domain and half from another.

in PHP this is something like

```
$domains = array('domain1', 'domain2', 'domain3');
$domainIdx = 0;

function getDomain(){
    $rVal = $domains[$domainIdx];
    $domainIdx = $domainIdx++ >= count($domains) ? 0 : $domainIdx++;
    return $rVal;
}
```

which I call every time I render an image to get a domain for it. How could I do something similar in a mixin in SASS so when CSS is generated it will distribute all URLs between the domains list?

Comment: This sounds like something better solved with a load balancer.

Comment: It's actually a web page loading optimisation hack and does not relate to load balancing. Will try out the solutions on Monday and reward accordingly! Pretty thanks mates :)

Answer (score 1):

In your Compass configuration file (ie. `config.rb`), you can use the [`asset_host`](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/configuration-reference/) function, like this:

```rb
asset_host_list = ['domain.com', 'domain.org']
asset_host do |asset|
  "http://%s" % asset_host_list[asset.hash % asset_host_list.length]
end
```

But, I agreed with @cimmanon, this approach is weak.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can port exitsting code to SASS pretty straightforwardly:

```
$domains:        'domain1.com' 'domain2.org' 'domain3.net'
$current-domain: 1

@function get-domain()
  $domain: nth($domains, $current-domain)
  $current-domain: $current-domain + 1
  @if $current-domain > length($domains)
    $current-domain: 1
  @return $domain
```

You can then use it like this:

```
@for $i from 1 through 10
  .element-#{$i}
    background-image: url("http://#{get-domain()}/images/foo.png")
```

Demo: http://sassbin.com/gist/5831644/

Also, you've got a couple of bugs in your PHP snippet. The correct code would be:

```
$domains = array('domain1', 'domain2', 'domain3');
$domainIdx = 0;

function getDomain(){
    global $domains, $domainIdx;
    $rVal = $domains[$domainIdx];
    $domainIdx = $domainIdx + 1>= count($domains) ? 0 : $domainIdx + 1;
    return $rVal;
}
```

And @cimmanon is absolutely right. Such approach to load balancing is amateurishness and poor practice.